# Dual of the fact that equalizers are dependent sums over the identity type

Tags: category-theory, type-theory

An equalizer of $A$ along two morphisms $f, g : A \to B$ can be thought of as a dependent sum over an identity type ([see nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equalizer#in_type_theory)):

$$A|_{f = g} = \sum_{a : A} (f(a) = g(a))$$

Does this idea have a dual? Can we somehow express a coequalizer (quotient type) using dependent products and whatever the "dual of an identity type" is?

Comment: I can't say for sure that the answer is no, I am not an expert in homotopy type theory, but I strongly suspect that to be the case based on my intuition (primarily from coequalizers in $\mathbf{Set}$). The correct type to form coequalizers is the [quotient type](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quotient+type), which doesn't admit an obvious description in terms of dependent products. Moreover, computing coequalizers is hard in $\mathbf{Set}$, since you have to compute the equivalence relation on $B$ generated by the relations $f(a)\sim g(a)$ for all $a\in A$, which is hard.